# INNER JOIN using a particular string in SQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have a table which has an id Ifb422928bf1de68ee038d86dbfd0a7f338519d5b and the other table has a column called rev_message whose value is tdf#103965: set DisableFlags for SID_PARASPACE_INCREASE/DECREASE

Change-Id: Ic60b987d16e3ef97413a38ec5a1ddd6d1d7f93f8. I wanted to pluck the value of Change-Id in this and inner join with the id of the other table. Can someone tell me how to do it?

I tried using

`INNER JOIN t_revision on t_change.ch_changeId like '%'+t_revision.rev_message+'%'`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
INNER JOIN t_revision on t_change.ch_changeId LIKE CONCAT('%', t_revision.rev_message, '%'); '
```

Answer (score 0):

For the example that you provide, here is another way:

```
INNER JOIN t_revision 
ON t_change.ch_changeId = SUBSTRING_INDEX(t_revision.rev_message, ' ', -1)
```

This assumes that the string you are looking for is always at the end of the string and preceded by a space.